# Python3 DEFAULT (implicit) unicode UTF-8 normalization: how to?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, normalization, python-unicode

Yepp, this is way not-the-first question about unicode normalization in Python.

As many folks know, there are "same" unicode letters which are "not the same" (and even string lengthes differ!):

```
In [1]: s='å'                                                                                        

In [2]: import unicodedata                                                                            

In [3]: q=unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s)

In [4]: q
Out[4]: 'å'

In [5]: s
Out[5]: 'å'

In [6]: s == q
Out[6]: False

In [7]: len(s), len(q)
Out[7]: (1, 2)
```

So, the question is: **Is there a way to set DEFAULT normalization (say, "NFC") for all and every `.decode("utf-8")` calls?**

I mean, can I add a hook (or whatever) to *really normalize* any input?

I've faced the problem handling input from different browsers in a backend API…
Sometimes it arrive in NFD (for unknown reason) and make searches to fail.

PS. I do not want to "fix" all and every input routines to re-normalize what they get (**already done** and dislike it).

PPS. I'd like to have something like

```py
class mystr(str):
    '''
    str(object='') -> str
    str(bytes_or_buffer[, encoding[, errors]]) -> str
    '''
    def __init__(self, *av, **kw):
        self._default_norm = kw.pop('utf_normalize', 'NFC')
        super().__init__(*av, **kw)
        if kw.get('encoding', sys.getdefaultencoding()).lower() in ('utf-8', 'utf8'):
            self = unicodedata.normalize(self._default_norm, self)
...
_builtin['str'] = mystr # "is this a real life, or just a fantasy"©…
```

Comment: [Unicode normalization forms](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15).

Comment: I know. And I have quite different question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no such hook; you'll have to write your own wrappers (eg. a function that wraps `open()` and applies your desired normalisation on the fly to the input or output stream).

Comment: When comparing text like in a searching scenario, there are discrepancies to consider at so many levels, like encoding (eg. UTF-8 vs. 8-bit codepages), spelling ("normalisation" vs. "normalization"), inflection ("word" vs. "words", "foot" vs. "feet"), synonyms ("fix" vs. "repair")... Unicode normalization is just another one, probably located between encoding and spelling. If the libraries you use don't handle it for you, then it's your work to do it, as part of the plaster you put between the bricks.

Comment: Maybe there's one misunderstanding on your side: there is no default normalization – by default, text isn't normalized at all. It's perfectly fine (technically) to have both `s` and `q` in the same string. Some sources may yield text in one normalization form or the other, but typically there are no guarantees whatsoever, so if you need normalized text, you need to normalize yourself.

Comment: "make searches to fail" - at least some DBMS and search engines have support for handling unicode  normalisation; if that  is where you are searching it may be worth asking a more specific question about how to search with unicode in these particular environments.

Comment: Yepp, we use postgresql. But pg12 (which is already in prod among others) has no support for unicode normalization and I'm not in control to change it. Here we are.

Comment: It's still unclear to me, why we have **default** charset (`utf-8`) in `.decode()`, but may not have **default** normalization scheme (like `NFC`) too?

Take a look at:

`encoding defaults to sys.getdefaultencoding().
errors defaults to 'strict'.
`

I just want a counterpart to `sys.getdefaultencoding()` or alike.

Comment: Normalization just isn't part of encoding (even though it's closely related). It's like if you want all of your input to be in uppercase, you have to call `.upper()` at any entrypoint... If the form argument of `unicode.normalize()` had a default argument, you'd still have to call the function. I think what you want is *implicit* Unicode normalization, not a default scheme. This could be something like the newline substitution Python performs for text streams, but I don't think it exists.

Comment: @lenz, yes, your'e right, I want implicit action similar to newline handling...

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no built-in explicit functionality to do this for you. However, Python lets you easily replace or wrap built-in classes, so it's not hard to build your own string type with the desired behavior.

Comment: But noone will return this new class :(